# How to (pre)fix path for vite proxy if server sends 302 redirect

Tags: redirect, proxy, vite

I have a vite proxy configuration like so:

```
server: {
    port: 4200,
    host: 'localhost',
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
```

But of course when the backend responds with a 302 and a redirect url the `/api` prefix is missing and thus the redirect ends up with a 404 :-(

How am I supposed to fix this?

EDIT:

It is probably not the best thing to do but I have added a custom header and handle that one in the backend.

```
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000',
        changeOrigin: true,
        headers: {"proxy-prefix": "/api"},
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
```